# how to create multiple data frames from another dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

iam new in python and wanna create multiple data frames from another dataframe in a loop.
i have a dataframe like below and want to create dataframes for each period and want to put period  id as a name for each created dataframes.

```
id      period
1       1167
2       1167
3       1168
4       1168 
5       1169
6       1169
...
```

i have tried something like below

`for i in KAI_stores['period']: i=pd.DataFrame()`

in the end i want to have

```
first df named as 1167
id    period
1     1167
2     1167

second df named as 1168
id    period 
3     1168
4     1168
and ... for each period
```

Comment: This is not necessarily the best strategy. What is your use case for creating multiple data frames rather than applying calculations to the "period" group?

Comment: i did t get what you mean but suppose i have 10 periods in the first dataframe and in the end i want to have  
1167 
id period
1 1167
2 1167
 
1168 
id period
3 1168
4 1168
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dict with 3 entries where the key is the period and the value is the corresponding subset dataframe:

```
dfs = dict(list(df.groupby('period')))
```

```
>>> dfs[1167]
   id  period
0   1    1167
1   2    1167

>>> dfs[1168]
   id  period
2   3    1168
3   4    1168

>>> dfs[1169]
   id  period
4   5    1169
5   6    1169
```

**Don't use this**

If you really want to create 3 variables `df1167`, `df1168` and `df1169` that can be direct accessible by their name:

```
for period, subdf in df.groupby('period'):
    locals()[f'df_{period}'] = subdf
```

```
>>> df_1167
   id  period
0   1    1167
1   2    1167

>>> df_1168
   id  period
2   3    1168
3   4    1168

>>> df_1169
   id  period
4   5    1169
5   6    1169
```