# Create few Data Frames from existing Data Frames based on unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, unique

My DF looks like below

```
x  y  z  b
1  2  3  Max
12 32 8  Max
1  2  3  Jon
12 32 8  Max
1  25  3  Jon
12 32 81  Anna
```

So I need to based on column b, take unique values (in this case: Max, Jon, Anna) and create 3 new df like this:

df_1:

```
x  y  z  b
1  2  3  Max
12 32 8  Max
12 32 8  Max
```

df_2:

```
x  y  z   b
1  2  3   Jon
1  25  3  Jon
```

df_3:

```
x  y  z   b
12 32 81  Anna
```

I was looking for the answer but I don't know how can I create new DF's. Do you have any ideas? Of course in original DF there is more unique values.

Regards
Tomasz

Comment: `df[df['b'] == 'Max']]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `locals()` to create variable dynamically:

**Update**

> Do you have maybe idea how instead of calling DF: DF_1, DF_2, DF_3 using unique names? I mean DF_Max, DF_Jon, DF_Anna and save every DF into excel?

```
for name, subdf in df.groupby('b', sort=False):
    locals()[f'df_{name}'] = subdf
    subdf.to_excel(f'{name}.xlsx', index=False)
```

```
>>> df_Max
    x   y  z    b
0   1   2  3  Max
1  12  32  8  Max
3  12  32  8  Max


>>> df_Jon
   x   y  z    b
2  1   2  3  Jon
4  1  25  3  Jon


>>> df_Anna
    x   y   z     b
5  12  32  81  Anna
```

---

**Old answer**

```
for i, (_, subdf) in enumerate(df.groupby('b', sort=False), 1):
    locals()[f'df_{i}'] = subdf
```

```
>>> df_1
    x   y  z    b
0   1   2  3  Max
1  12  32  8  Max
3  12  32  8  Max

>>> df_2
   x   y  z    b
2  1   2  3  Jon
4  1  25  3  Jon

>>> df_3
    x   y   z     b
5  12  32  81  Anna
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68969956/15239951

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68268034/15239951

Comment: IMHO, a very bad practice to suggest, at the minimum I would add a warning. This can have unexpected consequences such as overwriting variables

Comment: Thanks mate! And do you have maby idea how insted of calling DF: DF_1, DF_2, DF_3 using unique names? I mean DF_Max, DF_Jon, DF_Anna and save every DF into excel?

Comment: I updated my answer according your comment.

Comment: You are my today's hero bro :D THANKS A LOT!

Comment: @Tmiskiewicz keep in mind that setting variables like this is a very bad practice, especially since here you really *do not need* to do this just to save a file

Comment: @Corralien UV due to DV

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby('b')` and make a dictionary:

```
dfs = {k:v for k,v in df.groupby('b')}
```

This is an efficient structure to save arbitrary keys. Especially if you do not know the number of groups in advance.

You can then access the dataframes by key:

```
>>> dfs['Max']
    x   y  z    b
0   1   2  3  Max
1  12  32  8  Max
3  12  32  8  Max
```

Comment: @mozway. I did the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> Anna, Jon, Max = list(zip(*df.groupby('b')))[1]
```

Or:

```
>>> Anna, Jon, Max = [x for _, x in df.groupby('b')]
>>> Anna
    x   y   z     b
5  12  32  81  Anna
>>> Jon
   x   y  z    b
2  1   2  3  Jon
4  1  25  3  Jon
>>> Max
    x   y  z    b
0   1   2  3  Max
1  12  32  8  Max
3  12  32  8  Max
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,12,1,12,1,12],
                   'Y': [2,32,2,32,25,32],
                   'Z': [3,8,3,8,3,81],
                   'B': ["Max","Max","Jon","Max","Jon","Anna"]})
gb = df.groupby('B')
out = {}
for name, group in gb:
   out[name] = group
print(out['Max'])
# Output
    X   Y   Z   B
0   1   2   3   Max
1   12  32  8   Max
3   12  32  8   Max
```

**Method 2**

```
out = dict(tuple(df.groupby('B')))
```

**EDIT**

You can try [vars() or globals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars) as well

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,12,1,12,1,12],
                   'Y': [2,32,2,32,25,32],
                   'Z': [3,8,3,8,3,81],
                   'B': ["Max","Max","Jon","Max","Jon","Anna"]})
for name, group in df.groupby('B'):
    vars()[f"DF_{name}"] = group
```